# How to send the value in <s:property/> from jsp to action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to send the value attribute in `<s:property/>` from JSP to action class.
my `<s:property/>` is like this.

```
<input type="check box"><s:property value="option 1" />
<input type="check box"><s:property value="option 2" />
<input type="check box"><s:property value="option 3" />
<input type="check box"><s:property value="option 4" />
```

here all options are check boxes. value for options are coming from database. Now I want to send user clicked check box/boxes value/s to the java action class. how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Implementation with example is mentioned here, please try and let us know if it doesn't work:

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jsp-checkbox.shtml

Try using scriplets <% option 1 %>" to populate values of server to checkbox

Comment: actually option 1 option 2 so on are the properties in my java class. using jdbc code i set the values for options. so if i use scriplets am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `name` attribute with a unique values for all checkbox input type like below

```
<input type="check box" name="checkBoxes0" ><s:property value="option 2"/>
<input type="check box" name="checkBoxes1" ><s:property value="option 3"/>
<input type="check box" name="checkBoxes2" ><s:property value="option 4"/>
```

Please see the name `checkBoxes` with a counter appended for all the checkbox input types. This will send all 
the checkbox values to the server side.i.e action class

Comment: should i have to give checkboxes0 checkboxes1 as variables in java class ?

Comment: Yes, you have to somehow receive it. There are lot of ways of doing it. Why are you not using `<s:checkboxlist>` from `struts`. I have just given the basic of how to send parameters on a list of checkboxes.

Comment: i used <s:checkboxlist list="communityList" name="community1" label="option1" />. But am getting exception called org.apache.jasper.JasperException

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tag

```
<s:checkboxlist list="communityList" name="community1" label="Option1" />


for this you must have 
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
```

you can go here  http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ui-tags-example-1.html

Comment: am getting this exception.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `<input type="check box" />`, in plain HTML it is `<input type="checkbox" />`.

In Struts you can use `<s:checkbox />` (or `<s:checkboxlist/>`, but I would start with the first).

Example:

```
<s:checkbox name="yourTargetVariable1" label="option 1" />
<s:checkbox name="yourTargetVariable2" label="option 2" />
```

Take a look at [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/checkbox.html), at [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/), and remember that only Struts tags **with a** `name` can be received by the action (otherwise, the values coming from the JSP can't be mapped to the variables in the Action).